# Ajax loaded html doen't show images in Firefox

Tags: jquery, ajax, firefox

I loaded some async HTML with

```
$.ajax({
    url: target,
    beforeSend: function () {
    },
    success: function (html) {
        targetTabBox.html(html);
    }
});
```

The URL: target is a "page" returning a HTML fragment (some text and images).
targetTabBox is a div

In IE all is well, but in firefox, I don't get to see my images only the alt text.
When I right-click the image and do properties I see:

http://localhost:3000/Product/Slapen/Laken-en-deken/%5CFoto%5CCms%5Cgots-logo.gif
Which is wrong, but:

When I look at the HTML with firebug I see:

```
<img src="\Foto\Cms\gots-logo.gif" alt="GOTS logo"/>
```

Which is as it should be!

What am I missing here?

Comment: Whats the output in firebug of `console.log(html);` if placed just above the `targetTabBox.html(html);` line.

Answer (score 1):

OK,

Its the backslash firefox is pulling some rfc's on me saying you must use forward slash, IE doesn't care.

```
<img src="\Foto\Cms\gots-logo.gif" alt="GOTS logo"/>
```

should be 
    [image: GOTS logo]

Thanks guys :-)

Guess I needed to type this in a Q&A site to see it.

Comment: Interesting, never noticed that before. Guess I never came across it. +1 for answering your own question.

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to format the right answer so it was html stripped:

```
<img src="/Foto/Cms/gots-logo.gif" alt="GOTS logo"/>
```

(I'm on a roll today)